# Outlook Request showing wrong time in timezones other than IST

Tags: java, timezone, icalendar

I am using iCalender API to send meeting request in JAVA. Currently it is working fine for IST timezone but the same application is deployed in CST/CDT or any other time zone it is showing wrong time in Outlook when meeting request is generated.

E.g. I am generating outlook request for today with start time as 10am and End time as 11am. When Outlook request is sent it displays 11.30 am 12.30 pm as start time and End Time respectively.

Please see below is the code how I am setting calendar content of request.

```
private BodyPart buildCalendarPart() throws Exception {

    BodyPart calendarPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    TimeZone timezone  = TimeZone.getDefault();
    long offset =  timezone.getOffset(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);

    Calendar startTime =  Calendar.getInstance();  
    startTime.setTime(taskDTO.getStartDate());  

    startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


    if(taskDTO.getStartTimeHrs().equals(12)) {
         startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    } else {
         startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, taskDTO.getStartTimeHrs());
    }

    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, taskDTO.getStartTimeMins());
    startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if(taskDTO.getStartTimeampm().equalsIgnoreCase(ApplicationConstant.AM))
        startTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);
    else
        startTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

    System.out.println("Start Date :"+startTime.getTime().toString());

    Calendar endTime =  Calendar.getInstance();  
    endTime.setTime(taskDTO.getDueDate());  

    endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    endTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if(taskDTO.getEndTimeHrs().equals(12)){
        endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    }else{
        endTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, taskDTO.getEndTimeHrs());
    }

    endTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, taskDTO.getEndTimeMins());
    endTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if(taskDTO.getEndTimeampm().equalsIgnoreCase(ApplicationConstant.AM))
        endTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    else    
        endTime.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);


    Date startDate = startTime.getTime();
    Date endDate = endTime.getTime();
    iCalendarDateFormat.setTimeZone(timezone);
    //check the icalendar spec in order to build a more complicated meeting request
    String calendarContent =
        "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
        "METHOD:REQUEST\n" +
        "PRODID: BCP - Meeting\n" +
        "VERSION:2.0\n" +
        "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
        "DTSTAMP:" + iCalendarDateFormat.format(startDate) + "\n" +
        "DTSTART:" + iCalendarDateFormat.format(startDate)+ "\n" +
        "DTEND:"  + iCalendarDateFormat.format(endDate)+ "\n" +
        "SUMMARY:Created New Task\n" +
        "UID:" + taskDTO.getTaskID() + "\n" +
        "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:"+taskDTO.getLoggedInUserEmailID()+"\n" +
        "ORGANIZER:MAILTO:"+taskDTO.getLoggedInUserEmailID()+"\n" +
        "SEQUENCE:0\n" +
        "PRIORITY:5\n" +
        "CLASS:PUBLIC\n" +
        "STATUS:CONFIRMED\n" +
        "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n" +
        "BEGIN:VALARM\n" +
        "ACTION:DISPLAY\n" +
        "DESCRIPTION:REMINDER\n" +
        "TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT00H15M00S\n" +
        "END:VALARM\n" +
        "END:VEVENT\n" +
        "END:VCALENDAR";

    calendarPart.addHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
    calendarPart.setContent(calendarContent, "text/calendar;method=CANCEL");

    return calendarPart;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any inputs on the same

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends how you format your date and time. Your sample code does not show how you defined your iCalendarDateFormat variable. I suspect that it is something like "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'" which indicates a date with UTC time (Form #2 at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5). So your 10am IST will translate into 4.5am in UTC time, and, when received, will then be translated into the local time of the receiving client.

If you really want to say "this event should show up at 10am no matter where the user/client might be", you should use a date with local time (Form #1 at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5). In other words, your iCalendarDateFormat should not include the final 'Z'.

Finally, a simple typo: you are sending an iMIP REQUEST but you set the calendarPart Content-Type to *"text/calendar;method=CANCEL"*. Some clients may not like this.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.currently i am using below time format private static SimpleDateFormat iCalendarDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmm'00'"); i am still facing the problem.when i create a meeting request from CST timezone and assignee in IST at that time it is showing me correct local time on which meeting is scheduled.but it is not working even CST to CST.